# Should i install all of the workload and indvidual tools in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, ide, web-deployment, visual-web-developer, web-deployment-project

i downloaded visual studio 2017 to start working , then i noticed the workloads and the individual tools should be installed , i marked them all and he total installing size was 80+ GB which will takes days and even weeks to be installed completely , my question is should i download all of these to start neatly and perfectly or it is just extra tools

Answer (score 0):

On the workload selection screen, every workload says clearly what function it is used for. Select the ones which will serve you according to your development plans. For example if you are going to develop games with C++, select the C++ game development.